# How to write a Linq expression for a SQL cross join?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am creating a report to list people in my database, according to user-defined filter criteria.  So, for example, I could filter by name, age etc.

```
var people = db.People.AsQueryable();
if (filterByName)
  people = people.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(nameFilter));
if (filterByAge)
  people = people.Where(p => p.Age == age);
```

Now, one of the filter criteria is to show people who have not had their required immunizations.  I have tables for `Immunization` and `PersonImmunization` (with a unique index on `PersonID, ImmunizationID`).  If someone is missing any `PersonImmunization` records, or if number of doses they have received is under the requirement, they should be included, otherwise not.

If I were writing a SQL query, it would be:

```
select p.*
from Person p
cross join Immunization i
left join PersonImmunization pi 
  on pi.PersonID = p.ID and pi.ImmunizationID = i.ID
where pi.ID is null or pi.Doses < i.RequiredDoses;
```

Now in order to make this part of my where clause, I need to express this using an `Expression` predicate:

```
if (filterByImmunizations) {
  Expression<Func<Person, bool>> nonCompliantImmunization = 
    person => <now what?>;
  people = people.Where(nonCompliantImmunization);
}
```

The first problem I have is how to work Immunizations into the expression.  Then, once I have it, I suspect that finding the non-compliant people might be more straightforward, but if you could include that in your answer, I'd much appreciate it!

**EDIT:**  I've been requested to explain why I'm so set on getting a solution using an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`.  The reason is because I have built a whole generic framework for writing complex, user-defined queries, in several different contexts.  To give you an idea of what's inside the engine, here's a snippet of what's inside my base class:

```
public abstract class QueryBuilder<T> where T : EntityObject {

  public static IQueryable<T> FilterQuery(IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<QueryConditionLite> filters, bool anyConditionSufficient) {
    ...
  }

  protected Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> GetPredicate(Expression<Func<TBase, double>> expression, IQueryCondition condition) { 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Then I have a `PersonQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder<Person>`, and within that I want to create a filter that shows the people who are non-compliant with their immunization requirements.  I think you will agree that query syntax just ain't gonna cut it.

Comment: @Nilesh - The question is dumbed down from my actual code in order to prevent confusion; please just accept as given that I need an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`, and query syntax is not sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your justification for prohibiting the valid, working solutions.

Comment: Why do you seem to think you can only have a query use a .Where(...)?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce edited per your request

Comment: @Tory, not sure what your question means, but maybe my recent edit will answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach it as a multi-part join:

```
var nonCompiantImmunization =
  from p in Persons
  from i in Immunizations
  let pi = PersonImmunizations.Where(x =>
    x.ImmunizationID == i.ID && x.PersonID == p.ID)
  where !pi.Any() || pi.Sum(x => x.Doses) < i.RequiredDoses
  select new { p, i };
```

**Edit:** To make it fit the `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` constraint, I suppose you could rephrase it as:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> nonCompliantImmunization = 
  person => (
      from i in Immunizations
      let pi = PersonImmunizations.Where(x =>
        x.ImmunizationID == i.ID && x.PersonID == person.ID)
      where !pi.Any() || pi.Sum(x => x.Doses) < i.RequiredDoses
      select true
    ).Any();
```

Comment: -1 Definitely not.  That loses both the cross join and the left join.  Plus, I need it as an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`; query syntax does not work.

Comment: @Shaul the expression is logically identical, you never *need* cross join and left join, the db will select the optimal execution plan.

Comment: @wendazhou Re-read the answer here, and you will see that this only selects existing `PersonImmunization` records (losing the left join), and has no guarantee that all `Immunization` records are being included.

Comment: @Shaul: I see the difference now, your logic is counting the absence of a PI record as proof of absence. My logic should now mach yours.

Comment: OK, I've undone my downvote, but still no upvote because (a) `pi` is not an enumerable, so `pi.Any()` is wrong, should be `pi == null`; (b) even if you correct it, it'll be identical to @Magnus's answer, (c) which is still not sufficient, since I need an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`

Comment: `pi` *is* an enumerable in my code... the `.Where` clause `PersonImmunications` (which is just the PersonImmunizations table) returns an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see that now.  Still, `pi` shouldn't be an enumerable; we can rely on the fact that there will be no more than one record per person/immunization.  Edited question to show that.

Comment: Now I see your edit with the `Expression`.  Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write is like this instead:

```
var people = db.People.AsQueryable();
if(filterByImmunizations)
{
  people = from p in people 
           from i in db.Immunization
           from pi in db.PersonImmunization.Where(x => 
                x.PersonID == p.ID && x.ImmunizationID == i.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           where pi.ID == null || pi.Doses < i.RequiredDoses
           select p;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the right Linq syntax, but I specifically want it as an `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`.  The question is dumbed down from my actual code in order to prevent confusion; please just accept as given that query syntax is not sufficient for my purposes.